# ExceptionHandler import conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, jira-rest-java-api

The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler is getting conflict with a type defined in same type and the @ExceptionHandler is getting a error is not a annotation type

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler({ EmptyResultDataAccessException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleEmptyResultDataAccessException(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String mensagemUsuario = messageSource.getMessage("recurso.nao-encontrado", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        String mensagemDesenvolvedor = ex.toString();
        List<Erro> erros = Arrays.asList(new Erro(mensagemUsuario, mensagemDesenvolvedor));
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, erros, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }
    
    public static class Erro {
        private String mensagemUsuario;
        private String mensagemDesenvolvedor;
        
        //Constructor
        public Erro(String mensagemUsuario, String mensagemDesenvolvedor) {
            super();
            this.mensagemUsuario = mensagemUsuario;
            this.mensagemDesenvolvedor = mensagemDesenvolvedor;
        }
        
        
        //Getters Setters
        public String getMensagemUsuario() {
            return mensagemUsuario;
        }
        public void setMensagemUsuario(String mensagemUsuario) {
            this.mensagemUsuario = mensagemUsuario;
        }
        public String getMensagemDesenvolvedor() {
            return mensagemDesenvolvedor;
        }
        public void setMensagemDesenvolvedor(String mensagemDesenvolvedor) {
            this.mensagemDesenvolvedor = mensagemDesenvolvedor;
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Try to modifying the error when i get no content on a DeleteMapping

Comment: Either rename your class to something like `MyExceptionHandler` or only use the fully qualified name for the imported class, aka. `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler({ EmptyResultDataAccessException.class })` without the import...

Comment: I tried this, now it is accepting in the code, however when I access the localhost I get 500 internal server error and not the error of the way I defined

Comment: Ops, that 500 internal server error was a another problem in my code, whats luk2302 said worked for me, thank you